# PHP: Give An ID to File in XML

Tags: php, xml, count

Im using this code for create a xml file which is listing files' url and descriptions in directory. but i need to add in this xml also number of file. so i want to give to files a number (or ID), like 1 for file 2....n , like counter for every row how i can do this ?

thank you

```
<?php   

$myfeed = new RSSFeed();    

// Open the current directory (or specify it)   
$dir = opendir ("./");   
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {   
if (strpos($file, '.jpg',1)||strpos($file, '.gif',1) ) {   
$myfeed->SetItem("http://host.com/images/$file", "$file", "");   
}   
}   

// Output the XML File     

$fp = fopen('rss.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $myfeed->output());
fclose($fp);
echo $myfeed->output(); //lets see that

class RSSFeed {   
// VARIABLES   
    // channel vars   
    var $channel_url;   
    var $channel_title;   
    // items   
    var $items = array();   
    var $nritems;   

// FUNCTIONS   
    // constructor   
    function RSSFeed() {   
         $this->nritems=0;   
        $this->channel_url='';   
        $this->channel_title='';   
    }      
    // set channel vars   
    function SetChannel($url, $title, $description, $lang, $copyright, $creator, $subject) {   
        $this->channel_url=$url;   
        $this->channel_title=$title;   
    }   
    // set item   
    function SetItem($url, $title, $description) {   
        $this->items[$this->nritems]['url']=$url;   
        $this->items[$this->nritems]['title']=$title;   
        $this->nritems++;      
    }   
    // output feed   
    function Output() {   
        $output =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";   
        $output .= '<playlist version="0" xmlns = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/">'."\n";   
        $output .= '<trackList>'."\n";    
        for($k=0; $k<$this->nritems; $k++) {   
            $output .= '<track>'."\n";  
            $output .= '<location>'.$this->items[$k]['url'].'</location>'."\n";   
            $output .= '<image></image>'."\n";   
            $output .= '<annotation>'.$this->items[$k]['title'].'</annotation>'."\n";   
            $output .= '</track>'."\n";     
        };   
        $output .= '</trackList>'."\n";  
        $output .= '</playlist>'."\n";   
        return $output;   
    }   
};   

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, I don't think creating XML with `string`-functions is a good idea, rather use a parser like `simplexml`or `DOM`.

Assigning an `id` to each entry, you could take your `$k` in `function Output()`:

```
for($k=0; $k<$this->nritems; $k++) {   
    $output .= '<track>'."\n";  
    $output .= "<id>$k</id>\n";
    // (...)
    $output .= "</track>\n";  
}
```

or add `id` as attribute to the `<track>`-node:

```
$output .= "<track id=\"$k\">\n";
```